# VirtualBox: Bridging IP address into virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox

I want to bridge y.y.4.36 to my Virtual machine.

I can configure y.y.4.36 on Host. So routing to Host works and I can `ping y.y.4.36` from the internet:

```
$ ifconfig
eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet x.x.41.32  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast x.x.41.255
        inet6 fe80::5a20:b1ff:fe07:b375  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 58:20:b1:07:b3:75  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2851252  bytes 241129524 (241.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6722211  bytes 9634863759 (9.6 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0x92c00000-92cfffff  
eno2:0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet y.y.4.36  netmask 255.255.255.224  broadcast y.y.4.63
        ether 58:20:b1:07:b3:75  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        device memory 0x92c00000-92cfffff  
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         x.x.41.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno2
x.x.41.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno2
```

Note there is no default gateway for y.y.4.36.

I can easily set the VM to used Bridged Network, and set its address to y.y.4.36. But how do I make it reachable from the internet?

I expect I have to remove eno2:0 and then some how tell the virtual machine that it should use y.y.4.36 as its address and x.x.41.1 as its default gateway.

But how do I do that?

This does not work:

```
$ route add -net default gw x.x.41.1
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

because the VM does not have an address on x.x.41.*.

*Edit*

I have made a workaround. On Virtual Machine add another interface with host networking. Then:

```
ifconfig enp0s8 192.168.56.2
ifconfig eth0 y.y.4.36 netmask 255.255.255.224
route add -net default gw 192.168.56.1
# Force the src address to be y.y.4.36 and not 192.168.56.2
ip route replace default via 192.168.56.1 dev enp0s8 src y.y.4.36
```

On Host:

```
route add -host y.y.4.36 gw 192.168.56.2
```

So I route traffic through VirtualBox's host network (192.168.56.0/24).

It seems to work, but I believe there is a more conventional way to do accomplish giving y.y.4.36 to the VM.

Comment: If you can ping y.y.4.36 from the Internet there must be a route to it. Or you're using NAT/Port Forwarding. So on your local network remove the configuration for y.y.4.36 from your host and add it to your bridged VM. What's the problem here?

Comment: @roaima What should be the default gw for the VM?

Comment: You've said you want to bridge. So the configuration for the VM must be the same as for the host (but obviously a different IP address)

Comment: If you want to route, that's a totally different thing

Comment: I'm confused: you say "I want to bridge y.y.4.36 to my Virtual machine. I can configure y.y.4.36 on Host" : so the ip is on the host, not on the guest? Do you want that ip instead to be the ip of the guest? (as shown with your guest's eth0) ? It is unclear what you are trying to achieve (what are your LANs, what ip(s) should the guest have, what ip(s) should the host have). What subnets for all the LANs (you have some 255.255.255.0 and some 255.255.255.224?)

Comment: @OlivierDulac I can *put* the IP on the Host (using eno2:0), and if I do that, I can reach the Host using that IP-address. But I need it instead on the guest. The configuration of the Host is shown above (just remove eno2:0):  x.x.41.32/24 gw x.x.41.1. The configuration of Guest should be: y.y.4.36/27 gw ?. I can live with y.y.4.36/32 if it makes it easier. Please see the edit: It works, but I believe there should be a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
Your host is x.x.41.32  netmask 255.255.255.0 (ie, net is x.x.41.0 to x.x.42.255),
 and the gateway (to internet) is x.x.41.1. 
you want to setup a lan for your vms on x.x.4.36 netmask 255.255.255.224
 (hence on a subnet with 32 ips, x.x.4.32 to x.x.4.63 and that vm is x.x.4.36).
```

If you want that subnet to access the internet: one of many possibilities (TIMTOWTDI...): one of the vms (for exemple: x.x.4.36? or the host? or another one?) should have 2 interfaces : one in x.x.41.y, one in x.x.4.z, and have routing enabled, and have the default gateway x.x.41.1. The other vms should have as default gateway the x.x.4.z ip of that particular vm (or host).

Comment: Well, the router on y.y.4.z is not needed when I put y.y.4.36 on Host (as shown with eno2:0). I can access Host just fine using that. I believe the ISP has put y.y.4.36 in their router's ARP table, so it always goes to my server.